# ¿Cómo puedo crear un PDF o abrir un PDF y editarlo en mi aplicación de android?

Tags: java, android

mi aplicación consiste en un login, con dos formularios distintos en los cuales se deben generar un pdf para poder después adjuntarle y enviarlos por correo, no busco una aplicación en si.
No sé si se pueda crear un PDF, o en todo caso crear un botón en la misma aplicación en la cual abra un PDF y sólo lo edite agregando los datos y una imagen.

Comment: te recomiendo que te revises la libreria itext, es muy buena y sencilla

Comment: Hola @KonnAN. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrás explicar si buscaste algo, o intentaste resolverlo de alguna forma (por más que no haya funcionado)?

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, como dice Sergio Cv, probe con la libreria itext, pero no me resulto, creo que la utilice mal, y aun sigo buscando como hacerlo, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edito:

Android soporta generación de documentos PDF de manera nativa a partir del API 19 (Android 4.4 KitKat):

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html

---

Tienes la siguiente librería Java que te permite abrir y editar documentos PDF:

- https://pdfbox.apache.org/
- https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

El problema es que está orientado a Java de escritorio (usando AWT) por lo que el repositorio de github es un intento de portarlo a Android.

Ésta es otra opción (quizá mejor para usar en Android):

- http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html

Permite crear documentos PDF, pero no sé si permite abrirlos para edición.

Una opción más, bajo licencia LGPL:

- http://gnujpdf.sourceforge.net/gnujpdf.html

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! mi aplicación consiste en un login, con dos formularios distintos en los cuales se deben generar un pdf para poder después adjuntarle y enviarlos por correo, no busco una aplicación en si! Saludos.

Comment: Perdón, no sé si has editado la pregunta, pero entendí algo completamente diferente :) Modifico mi respuesta acorde.

Comment: Entiendo, perdón!, ojala pudieras ayudarme, gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira mi última edición. Desconocía que a partir del API 19 (Android 4.4 KitKat) se pueden generar documentos PDF de manera nativa.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, ahora estoy revisando una por una ..